# C# List.Sort doesn't sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a `List<T>` I want to sort, so I used `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`. My code didn't work as expected and after some debugging I found that while the order of the items contained within did indeed change, it didn't become sorted.
The code is here:

```
System.Comparison<Intersection> comp=(Intersection one, Intersection other)=>{//Sort sorts from lowest to highest
    if(one.index>other.index){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(one.index<other.index){
        return -1;
    }
    else if((one.point-one.node.position).sqrMagnitude>(other.point-other.node.position).sqrMagnitude){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
};
intersections.Sort(comp);
```

Trouble is, after the sort the items can be found in order such that the third item has index 7 while the fourth has 6. I thought that there might be something wrong with the comparison lambda, but I added a code which used the same function to compare sequential items, but it behaved correctly and sometimes returned 1,  so the problem is clearly elsewhere.
The afterward comparison:

```
for(int he=1; he<intersections.Count; he++){
    Debug.Log(comp(intersections[he-1], intersections[he]));
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or is my `List<T>.Sort` implementation faulty and I should just make my own sorting method?

The structure looks like this:

```
class Intersection{
    public PolyNode node;
    public int index;
    public Polygon poly;
    public Intersection sister;
    public bool is_out;
    public sbyte wallnum;
    public Vector2 point;
    public int list_index;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what your input is, but are they never equal (0)?

Comment: What about equal values? A comparison which never returns 0 looks dodgy to me. Can you provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? (If you can do it by just comparing *one* property, that would really help...)

Comment: show the data structure you are trying to sort..

Comment: You can simplify your first two statements (if index is a `int`), `if (one.index != other.index) { return one.index - other.index } else if ((one.point- .....`, that is why Comparison returns a `int` so you can do those subtractions and just return the result.

Comment: @CodeCaster it's theoretically possible for them to be equal, but highly unlikely and practically useless to me.
@JonSkeet I don't think I can provide a complete program that would demonstrate the behavior. This is for Unity, but I posted here because I just need to know if my code is faulty or the `Sort` is.
@DJKRAZE will edit it in in a bit.
@ScottChamberlain Thanks for the input, but I don't think that would help me with the problem at hand.

Comment: What is more likely, Sort() being broken or your code? Create a small, preferably simpler program that reproduces the behavior and try to fix it from there.

Comment: @CodeCaster My code, but.. the for that compares the values in the "sorted" `List` is immediately after the call to `Sort`. There is literally nothing between those two that could mess the order up. That's why I'm stumped.

Comment: @Tomeamis: Many standard sorting algorithms, e.g. QuickSort, routinely compare an item to itself (and of course expect that comparison to return `equal`).

Comment: @CodeCaster: I meant to direct that comment at the OP, not you - fixed now, sorry.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I did not know that. I will try to adjust my code accordingly and see what happens. As a side question: Why do they do that?

Comment: They don't explicitly set out to do so, but it's convenient to just pick a pivot value and then blast through the array (which includes the pivot value itself) and compare each value to the pivot from either end. Not all implementations do it this way, but some do.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx for the algorithms List.Sort() uses and see Wikipedia for how those algorithm work. :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yup, added an equality comparison and it works like a charm. All the implementations of *Sorts I've ever seen have just made one check to see if item was greater (or smaller in some implementations) and went from there. They sorted correctly, so I still don't see the point. I would be grateful for an explanation or maybe a link to some.  
Anyways, if you could just make your comment into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've implemented both Quicksort and Insert Sort before, and they both just used either the < operator or the > operator. Though after reading the Wikipedia article on Quicksort a bit more attentively, it says that some implementations may partition into 3 areas: larger than, smaller than, and equal to pivot. I still wonder about the specific implementation that would totally screw up the order if equal elements compared as smaller though...

Comment: @Tomeamis: Consider the following sort algorithm intended to sort into descending order: *search for the first pair of adjacent elements A and B such that A is smaller that B; if no such pair of elements exists then terminate, otherwise, swap them and start again*. This sort is inefficient on large lists but efficient on small lists and so could be used instead of quicksort when the list is known to be small. What does this algorithm do when the list has two elements, equal to each other, and is given a comparison function that says that the first equal item is smaller than the second?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To expand on 500 Internal Server Error's (correct) answer, Quicksort requires a well-behaved comparison function.  You are *required* to provide a comparison that:

- is reflexive: an item **must** compare equal to itself
- is antisymmetric in inequality: if A is greater than B then B **must** also be smaller than A
- is symmetric in equality: if A is equal to B then B **must** also be equal to A
- is transitive: if A is equal to B and B is equal to C then A **must** be equal to C. If A is greater than B and B is greater than C, then A **must** be greater than C. And so on

In short, a *[total ordering relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)* must be supplied. Your comparison algorithm violates many of these requirements. Any time you fail to provide a total ordering relation, bad things can happen. The algorithm can crash, it can go into infinite loops, or it can return an unsorted list.

For a longer discussion, see my four-part series on common ways that I've seen incorrect comparison algorithms written:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/01/20/bad-comparisons-part-one/

Comment: This is a totally overly-complex answer. Why not SHOW code that demonstrates how the OP may fix his issue and mine without plugging your article?

Comment: @ScottyMacDev: Why not write an answer you like better to this eight-year-old question that the user accepted the answer to?  Then we can all learn from your wisdom and the site will be improved.

Answer (score 6):

As others also noted, your comparison function never return a result of zero (equal), but List.Sort relies on the comparison function to return equal when an item is compared to itself.